# Change variable name from function

Tags: javascript, variables

I was wondering if it is possible to change the name of a variable from a function paramater

eg.

```
function(name, content) {
    var name = content;
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't directly support dynamic variable names. Generally, if the name as well needs to be variable, it's better to define it as a property of a containing object.

Comment: In the example given you're re-assigning the value of `name` to the value of `content` but you can't change the name of the variable in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible. The closest you can get to that is to rename an object property like:

```
var something = { name: 'me' };
console.log('something', something);

something.content = something.name;
delete something.name;
console.log('something', something);
```

or as a function:

```
const rename = (something, oldPropertyName, newPropertyName) => {
  something[newPropertyName] = something[oldPropertyName];
  delete something[oldPropertyName];
};
```